# Font size continues to shrink when container stops shrinking when using "vw" for size metric. Why?

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xaYFD/)

I have 2 textboxes inside a container and I have text inside them whose `font-size` properties have been specified using the "vw" metric, in which the size is proportional the parent containers size. As you shrink and enlarge the container, the font sizes decrease. However, I have specified a `min-width` for the textboxes and the container, but the font size continues to decrease, even after the parents stop shrinking. Does anyone know why this is occuring?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="textbox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 850px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #999999;
}

.textbox{
    float: left;
    width: 30%; 
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 4.9% 0 4.9%;
    padding: 0 4.9% 0 4.9%;
    min-width: 250px;
}

.textbox p{
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewport units have no relationship to their parents, rather they scale directly to the size of the browser window. If you want to keep the text proportional in size to the parent element I suggest once the window resizes to a point where the text is unacceptably sized, use a media query to reflow the layout or resize the text.

Comment: Ah okay. Some misinformation on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the viewport minimum size using:
`@viewport {
   min-width: ##px;
 }`

Of course it would prevent resizing of the window below the given width, it all depends on what you want.